# msginit email address command line argument?

Tags: linux, internationalization, gettext

msginit prompts for an email address. Is there a way to tell msginit what email address to use without being prompted for it such as a command line argument?

```
cat >hellogt.cxx <<EOF
// hellogt.cxx
#include <libintl.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <iostream>
int main (){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    bindtextdomain("hellogt", "./");
    textdomain( "hellogt" );
    std::cout << gettext("hello, world!") << std::endl;
}
EOF
g++ -ohellogt hellogt.cxx
xgettext -d hellogt -o hellogt.pot hellogt.cxx
msginit -l es_MX -o spanish.po -i hellogt.pot
```

Comment: Quoting JS: "Downvoters: please provide comments. – Jon Skeet May 8 at 9:25"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is due to `msginit` using `/usr/lib64/gettext/user-email` to prompt for your email. If you instead run `msginit` with the `--no-translator` option it should assume it's being run non-interactively and not prompt you:

```
msginit --no-translator -l es_MX -o spanish.po -i hellogt.pot
```

Comment: I overwrote `/usr/lib64/gettext/user-email` as `echo <my email address>`. This is also a (more drastic) solution.

Comment: You can also create the file `~/.muttrc` containing the line `set from=you@example.com`. But msginit will still prompt if you want to use: 1) `you@example.com`, or 2) `you@localhostname`.